# appengine-web.xml - XML error validating

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine

when I try to deploy my App Engine Project, the following Valditation Error is shown:

> An internal error occurred during: "Deploying Guestbook to Google".
>   XML error validating C:\Users\Adrian\workspace\Guestbook\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml against C:\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.5.0.r36v201105092302\appengine-java-sdk-1.5.0\docs\appengine-web.xsd

Here is my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>adrianschaeferandroid</application>
    <version>1</version>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <static-files>
        <include path="/favicon.ico" />
    </static-files>
    <static-files>
        <include path="stylesheets/main.css" />
    </static-files>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Can anyone see the Validation Error? Shall I post the appengine-web.xsd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can only have 1 `static-files` element. if you have multiple `include`, you should nest them all within a `static-files` element.

thus the correct appengine-web.xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>adrianschaeferandroid</application>
    <version>1</version>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <static-files>
        <include path="/favicon.ico" />
        <include path="stylesheets/main.css" />
    </static-files>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find it a lot easier to not make such errors if you configure your app GAE/Java app using an app.yaml file to generate both the web.xml and appengine-web.xml: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml